# 3D Rendering in React Native

Tags: react-native, canvas, webview, 3d

I want to render a three-dimensional cube with images on its six surfaces in React Native, that can be rotated by the user. First, I wanted to use react-native-canvas, but 3D rendering isn't possible within such a canvas.

My second idea was a Web View, that is shown in React Native and that renders the cube. The big disadvantage of this solution is, that a internet connection is necessary. Furthermore, maybe the performance isn't that good this way.

So, do you have any idea how to solve my problem? Thanks for all responds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you use a javascript framework called three.js. it is designed to do exactly what you are looking for.